# Captures the image from camera and load image into imageview of another activity

Tags: android, xml

i am getting a problem in fetching an image captured by camera into image view of another activity so please, find out the problem.....

```
      public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  

                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

and the onActivityresult() is

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data,Uri mCapturedImageURI)
   {

       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST&&resultCode==RESULT_OK)
         {
           String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}; 

           Cursor cursor = managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null, null, null); 
           int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); 
           cursor.moveToFirst(); 
           String picturepath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
           Log.d("TAG", "getLastImageId::path " + picturepath);
           Intent   camintent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,GalleryActivity.class);
             camintent.putExtra("imagePath",picturepath );
             startActivity(camintent);
 }
}
```

and my another(receiving) activity is........

```
      private void getData(){

        String ps=getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");
        img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ps));
     }
```

Comment: "_I am getting a problem..._" And what problem would that be?

Comment: image can not be retrieved in another activity......

Comment: Log.d("TAG", "getLastImageId::path " + picturepath);, what is the op of this log. if its content uri , then first u need to convert it to file path.

Comment: What do you mean "other activity." You mean, `GalleryActivity.class` on `getData()` is not getting the imagePath? IS there a error in the log?

Comment: @soundsofpolaris it doesn't show anything thing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data,Uri mCapturedImageURI)
   {

       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST&&resultCode==RESULT_OK)
         {
           Bitmap bitmapImage = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");
           Intent   camintent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,GalleryActivity.class);
           camintent.putExtra("bitmap", bitmapImage);
           startActivity(camintent);
 }
}
```

And retrieve the Bitmap Image in second Activity

```
private void getData(){

        Bitmap bitImage=getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bitmap");
        img.setImageBitmap(bitImage);

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here for an example on how to launch the camera and then retrieve the image:
[Capture Image from Camera and Display in Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity)

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }  
}
```

If you want to pass the results between two different activities after receiving the image from the camera, you could save the bitmap as a file and then read it in the second activity.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood.  I thought that the receiving activity was the "other" one

Comment: Edited my original post. Try saving the image into a file in the first activity and reading the file in the second activity.